# Proxy server or how to get a static IP

Tags: proxy, static-ip-address

I need to access a webservice which requires an ip which is in the provider's whitelist of IP's
Therefore I would need a static IP in order to access this machine from multiple machines.
So I was wondering how to achieve this best.
Is there a free proxy service where you can get a static IP?
Or DynDns maybe?

I look forward to hearing your thoughts.

Comment: dyndns does not give you a static address, a proxy might work, depending on what kind of service. Or you just ask your internet provider for a static address. Also virtual servers come for a few cents a month these days.

Comment: A virtual server would be an option of course. But I would have to pay attention to the traffic that I pass through. That's why I would prefer having s.th. without traffic limitations

Comment: Have you tried QuotaGuard? https://www.quotaguard.com/static-ip

Comment: no, I was hoping for a free of charge solution.

Comment: Have you found a solution? I'm facing a similar problem. Thanks.

Comment: unfortunately not. at least no reliable free service

Comment: I see you are looking for a free or hosted solution, but for anyone who is interested in getting this working in the cloud, here's a great description for how to do it with AWS: https://spin.atomicobject.com/2018/01/17/secure-http-proxy-static-ip/

Comment: @Jimmery an important note on QuotaGuard's proxy: it appears the initial authentication *to the proxy* is not, by default, secure:

"We are also testing HTTPS proxy endpoints, please contact us if you want to trial it. With HTTPS endpoint your initial CONNECT request will be also encrypted, this protects proxy credentials and remote hostname but will require additional TLS handshake. …"

http://support.quotaguard.com/support/solutions/articles/12000037702-is-the-http-proxy-secure-when-accessing-https-services-

So: when using an HTTP proxy endpoint your credentials aren't encrypted.