# Using a proxy IP to access an API in flask application

Tags: flask, proxy, vpn

I am developing a flask application that needs to consume an API and that requires that I should have US based IP address. My problem is very similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26368161/proxy-server-or-how-to-get-a-static-ip) but I can avail services like [QuotaGuard](https://www.quotaguard.com/static-ip) or [VPNStaticIP](http://vpnstaticip.com/). I want to ask:

- Does anyone know about these services? Am I on the right track?
- How would I configure my flask application **which I am still developing** to use a proxy IP. From [QuotaGuard](https://www.quotaguard.com/static-ip) website:

> When you sign up you will be provided with a unique username and password that you can use to configure a proxy service in your application: username:password@static.quotaguard.com:9292
>   Blockquote

How would I go about this?

Comment: I don't know if you're going to use a proxy or VPN. But if you go with a proxy, you can install **proxychains** and configure it so that you can send your requests through this proxy. It doesn't really have anything to do with Flask.

Comment: Thanks I will look into this.

Comment: Just to complete the discussion, i am using Digital Ocean Box now.